# Speed Up Storyboard Opening

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

When I open the storyboard file, it takes between 1-2 minutes to open because of the number of VCs I have in it. What is the best practice to speed it up? Should we move some VCs into different storyboard files? Should we use more xib files to reduce the number of elements in VCs? Any suggestions would be great on what poor practices we might have implemented to make the storyboard loading time so slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Good practice:**

1. Keep your `ViewControllers` in different `storyboard` which are not logically related to each other. It will
   considerably reduce story board rendering/opening time. It will also 
   very helpful to avoid conflicts in storyboard when working with
   teams.
2. Try to UI elements to `xib` file, like `tableViewCell`, `collectionViewCell`, `buttons`, etc
3. Try to customise UI objects using code rather than `IBInspectable`/`IBDesignable`.

**Bad practice:**

1. Keeping all viewControllers in single storyboard file. Because it will take much time to render all UI objects in storyboard file, and its position in storyboard.

Thanks

Comment: Perfect. I have moved a lot of things into separate storyboard files but is there anything else I can do? The problem becomes that we have a lot of segues between VCs so it becomes very difficult to see which segues go where when the VCs are in different storyboard files.

Comment: To reduce number of segues, initialise viewControllers using code. See my updated answer also.

Comment: You don't need to seperate every single VC out, keep them in logically related chunks. So you might have a settings.storyboard with 3 or 4 connected VC's that all relate to your settings and sub-settings.

Answer (score 1):

Please open two tab by using **command + T** in your `Xcode`, one for `ViewController` and other for `storyboard`. It will speed up your `storyboard` because by opening two tabs, `ViewController` and `storyboard` files are already loaded. For more help, Please see the attached image below.

[image: SpeedUp Storyboard]

Comment: I do that already but anytime I open the storyboard tab, it still takes a very long time to open.

Comment: Then you need to enhance your RAM.